# Relation between two-particle Green's function and density matrix elements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, many-body, greens-functions, matrix-elements

In the article https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.69.054305, the authors used the following relation between the 2-particle density matrix element and 2-particle Green's function to calculate the entanglement of a noninteracting electron gas.

$$
\rho^{(2)}(x_1,x_2;x_1', x_2')=-\frac12\mathcal G(x_1\tau_1,x_2\tau_2;x_1'\tau_1'^+,x_2'\tau_2'^+)
$$

No justification has been given for the relation probably because it's a known relation to the community. So, I wish to know whether there is any general relation between Green's function and the density matrix of a system.

Comment: Have you tried to compare the definitions of both quantities? See also [this related post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335721/difference-between-greens-function-and-density-matrix?rq=1).

Comment: The density matrix of a system is defined as, $\rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i><\psi_i|$ which is completely different from the definition of 2 particle Green's function in the paper.

Comment: But not the two-particle reduced density matrix, i.e. $\rho^{(2)}$...It is defined similarly to the two-particle Green's functions, namely in terms of an expectation value of field operators.

Comment: Yes, I understood that if we define 2 particle density matrices in that form, the relation is trivial. But my question is how that definition of 2 particle density matrix is the same as the usual definition of the density matrix.

Comment: First of all, that is clearly *not* what you ask in your question! Second, the two-particle reduced density matrix ($2$-RDM) as well as the two-particle Green's function are defined with respect to a specific state  / density operator $\rho$. The $2$-RDM is a reduced density matrix of $\rho$. As such it is a density matrix (for a two-particle system) as well (apart from normalization) and admits a spectral representation. Is that your question? If not, consider to edit the question and make clear what you do not understand.