# Constructing the Density Matrix from the $S$-Matrix

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, s-matrix-theory

The $S$-matrix (scattering matrix) in Peskin & Schroeder's Introduction to QFT  is given as
$$
 \langle p_1 p_2 \cdots | k_1 \cdots k_{n}\rangle_{in} 
$$
where $| k_1 \cdots k_{n} \rangle_{in} $ is an incoming many-body state and $\langle p_1 p_2 \cdots |$ is the measured outgoing state.

This is described the the time evolution of some Hamiltonian $H(t)$ (say $\phi^4$ theory for example)
$$
\lim _{T \rightarrow \infty}\langle p_1 p_2 \cdots |e^{-i H(2 T)}| k_1 \cdots k_n\rangle. \tag{4.87}
$$
Now this looks a lot like an element of the final density-matrix after time-evolution written in the basis of the output measured, like some reduced density matrix

$$
 |\psi \rangle = e^{-i H(2 T)}| k_1 \cdots k_n\rangle, \qquad\rho_{\psi}  = | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | 
$$
and
$$
\langle p_1 p_2 \cdots |\rho_{\psi} |  p_1 p_2 \cdots \rangle = |S|^2.
$$
I'm wondering if there's an equivalent statement somehow to the LSZ theorem that states that you can construct the final density-matrix through the $S$-matrix or the $n$-point correlation functions. I would think that through this I could construct any Green's function of states, where the 2-point [is related to the density matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335721/).

EDIT: Based on the comments, it seems that yes, this are indeed equivalent formulations?

Comment: There's too many undefined things here ...

Comment: @NorbertSchuch please help me clarify what is unexplained. I was thinking the notation was pretty standard

Comment: What is P&S? What are |p>, |k> - any state, some special state, how are they related to H, what is H, on which space does it act? What is S (e.g. how is it defined)? When I hear "S-matrix" I think of topological theories; not even that is uniquley defined. Is it about scattering theory?

Comment: Note that *all* information is in the n-point correlation functions, if you don't bound n. (Well, it might depend on your HIlbert space, once more.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch When you say all information is in the n-point correlation functions, do you mean all information needed for scattering amplitudes or something broader? Is there some theorem related to this that I could take a look at? Not OP here, just an interested bystander...

Comment: @doublefelix All the information about the density matrix is in the collection of all $n$-point correlation functions -- at least under certain conditions (spin systems on lattices, but also other lattice systems (e.g. bosonic modes), probably also in the continuum with a suitable notion of "all n-point correlations").

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Do you happen to know of any book or reference where I might find the proof of this theorem?

Comment: @doublefelix For the case of spins on latttices it is obvious - just take the correlation functions corresponding to a full basis of the space of operators. I'd say this should also apply beyond that scenario, but I'm sure it will fail if you just push to more and more general spaces or states.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Sorry, now it is my turn to not know why this is obvious. For "a full basis of the space of operators of spins on a lattice" you mean that I can construct the density matrix of an given state through computing $\langle S_i \cdots S_n \rangle $ over all my sites or something like this? Could you elaborate?

Comment: The keyword is "quantum state tomography". More generally, if the operators you consider span the state of all matrices, then their expectation values allow to reconstruct the state -- this is just linear algebra (any vector is fully determined by its scalar product with a set of basis vectors).